# How to disable jQuery Kladr plugin?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery kladr plugin for autocompletion of addresses Russia. 
How to disable the plugin if you select a different country?

Comment: Ask the author: https://github.com/garakh

Comment: I wrote to the author. Without result.

Comment: Replace the input by removing it from the parent container, then add kladr to the input when selected again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this until you find the "disable" or "dis-activate" in the documentation

```
var cityOptions = {
    token: '51dfe5d42fb2b43e3300006e',
    key: '86a2c2a06f1b2451a87d05512cc2c3edfdf41969',
    type: $.ui.kladrObjectType.CITY
}
$function() {
  $("#country").on("change",function() {
    if ($(this).val()=="Russian") {
      $("#address").kladr(cityOptions);
    }
    else {
      $("#address").replaceWith("<input/>".{id:"address"});
    }
  });
});
```